# How to extract a List from a JavaPairDstream?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm new to Spark and Spark streaming and am just making my first steps. It seems that I do not really understand how to get it to work.

I have a JavaPairDstream that contains `Tuple2<Integer,List<Integer>>`. The first Integer is a sensor id and the list is sensor readings.
I need to extract the list element so I can calculate the average of sensor readings.

I tried to use foreachRDD but it did not work for me. Can someone post a code snippet, pseudocode or some guidance how to do this ? Java 8 code will be appreciated too.

Thank you

Guy

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use `flatMapValues`

Pseudo code in Scala, but it would be very similar in Java:

```
val dStream = ... 
val flatten = dStream.flatMapValues(list => list)
```

For each key you will have one row per one element in the input list, then you can use reduce to calculate sum, average and other metrics

For example

```
Input:
key = 1, value = [1, 2, 3]
Output:
key = 1, value = 1
key = 1, value = 2
key = 1, value = 3
```